# SQL Dependency vs Change Data Capture (CDC)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency, change-data-capture

I am using CDC for database change notification.
But some suggested to not use CDC.
I found this other option SQL Dependency.
Which one is better option among SQL Dependency and CDC?

Comment: There is no better or worse absent requirements. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Without having read extensively on the two and their differences, one thing that jumps out immediately is the fact that CDC is only available on SQL Server Enterprise.  It also looks like CDC would use significant storage space and incurs a performance hit but SqlDependency is only recommended for a small number of dependent clients.